# Intergral approximation?

Tags: integration, approximation

For the integral:
$$I=\int^{t/2}_{-t/2} e^{i(\omega_1-\omega_2)t'}dt'$$
What would be the lower limit on $t$ for the approximation:
$$I\approx 2\pi \delta(\omega_1-\omega_2)$$
to hold?

I would guess (and this is only a guess) that it would be:
$$t>>\frac{1}{\min(\omega_1,\omega_2)}$$ If this is correct how would we show it, and if not what is the limit on $t$?

Comment: Your question is not completely clear to me. Your first integral has an exact evaluation for finite $t$, namely $\frac{2 \sin \left(\frac{(\omega_1-\omega_2) t}{2}\right)}{\omega_1-\omega_2}$. Therefore, the answer to your question depends on the meaning you assign to your $\approx$.